# Opengl fragment shader second color

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I have a problem with fragment shader, I want to get an effect where two different objects are illuminated with different light. Here is my main code:

```
glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glUniform1i(ShadowMapID, 1);
//Here I draw my first object
//Then I want to change light from my fragment shader to color2.
```

My fragment shader:

```
      // Ouput data
       layout(location = 0) out vec3 color;
       layout(location = 1) out vec3 color2; 
       void main(){
       //Here I calculate my color variables
       }
```

I have no idea how to achieve this effect. Do I have to write a second fragmentshader? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Not quite.

Think about what a fragment shader is; it gets run for every pixel on your screen. As such, it typically has *one* color output, denoting value of said pixel. Multiple outputs of fragment shader are used in advanced techniques such as MRT (multi render-targets), to avoid unnecessary geometry computations.

If you want to change a value of the light between the calls, you simply change the shader uniforms, and then just execute the drawcall again. Another, analogous solution is to use an UBO.

Writing different shaders is necessary if you have fundamental changes in logic; otherwise, they are often generic enough to make just data bindings' modifications enough for stuff like changing lights. (Changing the number of lights, though, is another story).

Comment: **+1**: Just wanted to clarify something -- fragment shaders run on fragments (fragments can cover an area smaller or larger than a pixel on the final display device). *Direct3D actually calls pixel shaders by the wrong name ;)* But anyway, since it runs on fragments, the pixels you see on screen are the result of blending one or more executions of fragment shaders with the pixels already in the framebuffer. Thus, multi-pass lighting is explainable as the same object drawn multiple times and blended together.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I knew someone would pick on that :). I didn't want to introduce additional complexity into that answer, but it seems I should've added at least a footnote. Thanks for the nice summary.